# Plotting Transverse Electric field frequency in Python

Tags: python-3.x, function, plot

How would you plot f(cβ)?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcxWk.png)

I'm getting straight lines instead of curves.

Comment: Okay, there's a function you'd like to plot. What have you tried?

Comment: %matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
ω_1 = np.pi*299792458/0.18
ω_2 = 2*np.pi*299792458/0.18
ω_3 = 3*np.pi*299792458/0.18
print (ω_1)
print (ω_2)
print (ω_3)
cβ = np.arange(-10000, 10000, 1)
f_1 = (np.sqrt(ω_1^2+cβ^2))/(2*np.pi)
f_2 = (np.sqrt(ω_2^2+cβ^2))/(2*np.pi)
f_3 = (np.sqrt(ω_3^2+cβ^2))/(2*np.pi)
plt.plot (cβ, f_1)
plt.plot (cβ, f_2)
plt.plot (cβ, f_3)
plt.show()
The graphs look fine when plotted individually, but when I plot them all on the same graph, they appear as straight lines.

Comment: I got it. I had to do some tweaking with the range of values of the cβ. I set cβ = np.linspace(-30, 30, 1000) and it appears just right. Thank you for taking an interest in helping me.